# Hosting Sub-Domain on Separate Server From Main Site

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain

I have one website (example.com) on our main server (server A). However, we have some files that we want to host on another serve (server B), but accessible via download.example.com.

I thought I had it setup correctly, but I appear to be missing something. I added an A Record to example.com's DNS Zone (download.example.com. pointing to server B's IP), but it doesn't seem to be working. I am getting server A's 404 page.

In server B, I created a domain with a website (download.example.com), so that should work, right?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. I hadn't set server B up properly to accept the subdomain.

Thanks for the help!

-Jack

Answer (score 0):

woops, reread your OP...

have you tried accessing the download.example.com server directly? i.e.,

```
http://download.example.com/somefilethatreallyexists
```

If that works, then it sounds like the request is still being passed to server A. You need to trace the request to establish whether or not it's being handed off to the right server.

Comment: can you expand upon that?

Comment: @greeblesnort: Not 100% sure what you mean. server b is up. I have a temp alias that my host gives me that is working just as it should. I hope I'm understanding your question... Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I just did a trace of the web request. Really weird. It's ending up at server B!

The A record is pointing to server B. However the NS records are pointing to server A. Note that these are the DNS server records for the root (example.com). Do I need to create a new DNS Server record for the subdomain?

Thanks!